# Validation rule is not working as expecting

Tags: apex, community, validation

Hi i got a requirement like create a validation rule based on probability.

The requirement is user cannot modify some custom field called forecast units If probability is under 70%

So, i write a validation rule like

```
AND(ISCHANGED( Forecast_Units__c ),Probability < 0.70)
```

It works fine but when i create any opportunity the validation doesn't work
can anyone help me

Answer (score 11):

According to the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISCHANGED)

> ISCHANGED function returns FALSE when evaluating any field on a newly created record.

So your validation will never fire when you are creating a record. You might want to add `ISNEW()` function which checks if you are creating a new record.

```
OR(
   AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISBLANK( Forecast_Units__c )), Probability < 0.70),
   AND(ISCHANGED( Forecast_Units__c ),Probability < 0.70)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because the validation will only fire on the field being changed. To make it work on creation you would need to use ISNEW

So I think the following will work updated based on Adrian's input and checking that Forecast_Units__c is populated.

```
 AND(Probability < .7, 
    OR(AND(ISNEW(),NOT(ISBLANK( Forecast_Units__c ))), 
       ISCHANGED(Forecast_Units__c)))
```

Comment: You missed a comma(,) between two and conditions as the template for OR is OR(condition1,condition2,...conditionN)

Comment: Would be more elegant (and more importantly, lower compile size) as `AND(Probability < .7, OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Forecast_Units__c)))`. DRY.

Comment: This formula would stop a user from creating a new opportunity with < 70% probability. I would guess this is not the intended behavior. Not clear from the original question if forecast units should be blank on creation or some pre-determined value.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This validation below is incorrect, the only thing you can learn from it is how to *DO NOT USE* a combination of `ISNEW()` and `ISCHANGED()` formulas in Validation Rules ))

```
AND(
 NOT( ISNEW()),
 ISCHANGED( Forecast_Units__c ),
 Probability < 0.70
)
```

Would allow you to bypass this validation when new record is created.

Comment: When new record is created his validation never fires, because `ISCHANGED()` always returns `false`.

Comment: @OlesMalkov You are right